# PHP one class using functions of another class created later in code

Tags: php, class, autoload

Let's say I have two classes (I have more, but keeping it simple)... I'm using autoloading, so I don't have to worry about including the class files themselves. Is it possible to do something like this, without reordering the code?

```
$class_horses = new horses($class_rabbits); 
$class_rabbits = new rabbits();
```

The reason I can't reorder this to have the rabbits class created first is because it's being loaded automatically, and reordering would mess up other dependencies anyway, so I'd still be in this situation.

Basically, I want the horses class to have access to one function in rabbits, if the rabbits class exists, but I'm not sure how to do this. I thought autoloading would make this clear, but I'm still a little lost. Is something like this even possible? I feel like I'm missing something and am probably asking a dumb question.

Comment: What about a static method that you can access via `rabbits::yourmethod()` instead of instantiating it?

Comment: "and reordering would mess up other dependencies anyway" --- your dependencies are already messed up. What if you fix the code that resolves dependencies (as the root of the problem) instead?

Answer (score 1):

I would really try hard to fix this earlier on, as type-hinting and the like is not possible, and  `$rabbit` in the below code cannot be trusted to be a `rabbits` instance, but you can do this using references:

```
<?php
class horses {
        private $rabbit;
        function __construct(&$rabbit){
                $this->rabbit = &$rabbit;
        }
        function test(){
                echo $this->rabbit->getName();
        }
}

class rabbits {
        private $name;
        function __construct($name){
                $this->name = $name;
        }
        function getName(){
                return $this->name;
        }
}



$class_horses = new horses($class_rabbits);
$class_rabbits = new rabbits('hopper');
$class_horses->test();
```